# The "mathematics" tag

Tags: discussion, tagging, tag-blacklist

I don't understand why there is a [tag](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mathematics) for "mathematics" when that is the title of this site. Does anyone think it should not be deleted?

Comment: I am with you on this. There are lot of useless tag's which are also not needed.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I agree -- we always remove tags that are the same as the title of the site, e.g. [wordpress] on wordpress, [apple] on apple, etc.

I have removed [mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mathematics) and I added `^math(ematics)?$` as a tag regex blacklist entry.

Comment: Dear Jeff, thanks for doing that.

Comment: Can we also black-list `equation(s)` as a tag? I'm rather tired of playing whack-a-mole with it. See discussion http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1363/tag-merging-and-synonyms/1936#1936 in another meta thread. (I'll clean up the remnants in a bit.)

Comment: @willie done, I added `^equations?$` as an intrinsic tag as well

Comment: `^math(ematic)?s?$`, would catch those who use the UK form as well :)