# Which are blacklisted tags and blacklisted phrases?

Tags: support, tag-blacklist, warnings, blacklist

There are many tags which are blacklisted. And so are some strings/words/phrases in the title.

Is it possible to have a list of them publicly available somewhere?

---

As I was told by a moderator [in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/25422533#25422533): "Some of the blacklisted input is more sensitive (some stuff that helps prevent certain types of spam). Blacklisted items that we've requested are probably safe to state publicly."

So could we have at least list of those which are safe to publish?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kyBH5oNQOS0

Comment: The above link is to the youtube video of: [George Carlin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_Carlin) - 7 Words You Can't Say On TV. See also Wikipedia article: [Seven dirty words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven_dirty_words).

Comment: [Is it safe? ... I can't tell you something's safe or not, unless I know specifically what you're talking about.](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0074860/quotes)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### Blacklisted tags

I will start here list of blacklisted tags based on past discussions and information I was given by Arthur Fischer [in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20352/conversation/list-of-blacklisted-tags-and-blacklisted-phrases). I made the post CW - it should be expanded if some new tags are blacklisted and if some other information can be added.

- [math](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math), [mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mathematics) See [The "mathematics" tag](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1647/the-mathematics-tag). These tags are also *intrinsic tags* for this site, [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210532/drop-or-change-automatic-migration-rejection-based-on-non-existing-tags#215921).
- [equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/equation), [equations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/equations) These tags are also *intrinsic tags* for this site. See the comments [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1647/the-mathematics-tag/1648#comment9114_1648).
- [gm.general-mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gm.general-mathematics) An *intrinsic tag* to facilitate migrations from MathOverflow; see [this answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/12517).
- [untagged](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged) What questions are tagged when they have no tags; see [What causes a question to be tagged as [untagged]?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/167879)
- [algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/algebra) See [Should the algebra tag be blacklisted?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6299/should-the-algebra-tag-be-blacklisted)
- [completeness](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/completeness) See [Blacklist the [completeness] tag](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21031/blacklist-the-completeness-tag) and also [this answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1363/tag-merging-and-synonyms/8691#8691).
- [graph](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graph), [graphs](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphs) See [Let's blacklist the [graph] tag](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8729/lets-blacklist-the-graph-tag)
- [homework](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homework) See [Fate of the (homework) tag: The community voted.... now what?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16425/fate-of-the-homework-tag-the-community-voted-now-what) and [(homework) tag should be deprecated (Voting's over! You won't believe what won!)](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14981/homework-tag-should-be-deprecated-votings-over-you-wont-believe-what-won)
- [proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/proof) and [proofs](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/proofs) See [[proof] tag (again)](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2110/proof-tag-again)
- [proof-strategy](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/proof-strategy) (and technically [proofs-strategy](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/proofs-strategy) based on how a regex was set up) See [this answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3763/tags-proof-strategy-and-proof-writing/21843#21843) and also conversations in chat [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20352/conversation/removing-proof-strategy-tag) and [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3740/conversation/blacklisting-proof-strategy).
- [number](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number) See [How about we blacklist [number]?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10302/how-about-we-blacklist-number/22558#22558)

### Other blacklisted input

- question titles cannot contain `$$` to prevent most display math; see [Using block (displayed) equations in question titles](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16946)

### Warnings

- In response to [Should the site have an automatic word filter for titles?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16573/should-the-site-have-an-automatic-word-filter-for-titles), some words trigger a warning when used in short titles. These words are often fillers that don't convey information. If used in a short title, the user is warned that the title may be insufficiently specific, but they don't prevent the question from being submitted even then, so one *can* ask about "Sections in a *very* ample line bundle".

  - anyone, difficult, doubt, easy, hard, help, interesting, please, problem, query, question, someone, stuck, very
- Titles (at least 15 characters long) without any lowercase letters (`^(?-i:\P{Ll}+){15,}$`); produce a **DON'T SHOUT!** warning
- Post bodies (at least 30 characters long) without any lowercase letters (`^(?-i:\P{Ll}+){30,}$`); produce a **DON'T SHOUT!** warning
- occurrences of `imageshack.us` in post bodies produce a warning in reaction to ImageShack reusing image URLs for advertising purposes; see [Ban ImageShack images because they are reusing old URLs for advertising](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/263771)

Comment: Wow, you are fast :D